# React native 0.57 build issues. Babel .configFile

Tags: react-native, babeljs, react-native-ios

Trying to run react-native run-ios but getting the following error:

```
@babel/core/lib/config/validation/options.js:97
    throw new ReferenceError(unknownOptErr);
    ^

ReferenceError: Unknown option: .configFile. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.
    at buildUnknownError (/Users/glenbeamson/Documents/Repos/Projects/ReactNative/RO2018fs/client/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/options.js:97:11)
    at /Users/glenbeamson/Documents/Repos/Projects/ReactNative/RO2018fs/client/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/options.js:83:57
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at validate (/Users/glenbeamson/Documents/Repos/Projects/ReactNative/RO2018fs/client/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/options.js:61:21)
    at loadConfig (/Users/glenbeamson/Documents/Repos/Projects/ReactNative/RO2018fs/client/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/index.js:37:48)
    at loadOptions (/Users/glenbeamson/Documents/Repos/Projects/ReactNative/RO2018fs/client/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js:72:36)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/glenbeamson/Documents/Repos/Projects/ReactNative/RO2018fs/client/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js:82:12)
    at compile (/Users/glenbeamson/Documents/Repos/Projects/ReactNative/RO2018fs/client/node_modules/@babel/register/lib/node.js:61:42)
    at compileHook (/Users/glenbeamson/Documents/Repos/Projects/ReactNative/RO2018fs/client/node_modules/@babel/register/lib/node.js:102:12)
    at Module._compile (/Users/glenbeamson/Documents/Repos/Projects/ReactNative/RO2018fs/client/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:77:29)
```

Have tried to `npm install --save react @babel/core @babel/cli` again to try to clear anything up and also tried `npm cache verify` but to no avail. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

package.json here

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.38",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "react": "^16.6.0-alpha.f47a958",
    "react-native": "0.57.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.0.0-alpha.10",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.0-alpha.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-external-helpers": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.48.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `.babelrc` file?

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: The answer below works in the majority of cases - delete the node_modules folder and then npm install. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting your `node_modules` folder, clean its `cache` and do a fresh `npm` or `yarn` install and it will work eventually.

Comment: How do we clean cache?

Comment: @dazza5000 try ```npm cache clean --force```